# Change the check box ticking color in material-desing

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

In angular, I'm trying to change the checkbox tickers and the input value underline to be green instead of the default purpul.

How can I fix this?

```
    <div class="label-input-block top-centre-form">
      <mat-form-field class="green-input"
        name="gadsCustomerId"
        formControlName="gadsCustomerId"
        id="gadsCustomerId">
        <mat-label>Select accounts</mat-label>
        <mat-select [formControl]="selectedCidList" multiple>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let cid of customer_list" [value]="cid.id">
            {{ cid.account_name }} [{{ cid.id }}]
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      
    </div>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Configure date range</ng-template>
    <div class="label-input-block top-centre-form">
      <mat-form-field class="green-input">
        <mat-label class="green-input">From Days Ago</mat-label>
        <input type="number"
          class="green-input"             
          name="fromDaysAgo"
          formControlName="fromDaysAgo"
          id="fromDaysAgo"
          matInput
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

https://imgur.com/a/1deeM0L

https://imgur.com/a/fFJJOxM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please read through [`angular-material theming documentation`](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) This contains the perfect instruction for theming you angular material components, for now, below a working example when I am using the `green-palette` to style all the components in a green theme. This will help you reach your final solution!

theme

```
...
$theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette);
$theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette);
...
```

full theme scss

```
// Custom Theming for Angular Material
// For more information: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat.core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue. Available color palettes: https://material.io/design/color/
$theme-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette);
$theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette);
// you can also do below
// $theme-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$green-palette, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$theme-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

// Create the theme object. A theme consists of configurations for individual
// theming systems such as "color" or "typography".
$theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $theme-primary,
      accent: $theme-accent,
      warn: $theme-warn,
    ),
    typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
  )
);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

html

```
<div class="label-input-block top-centre-form">
  <mat-form-field class="green-input" name="gadsCustomerId" id="gadsCustomerId">
    <mat-label>Select accounts</mat-label>
    <mat-select multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let cid of customer_list" [value]="cid.id">
        {{ cid.account_name }} [{{ cid.id }}]
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div class="label-input-block top-centre-form">
  <mat-form-field class="green-input">
    <mat-label class="green-input">From Days Ago</mat-label>
    <input
      type="number"
      class="green-input"
      name="fromDaysAgo"
      id="fromDaysAgo"
      matInput
    />
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<mat-label class="green-input">checkbox</mat-label>
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/4helyu?file=src%2Fexample%2Finput-overview-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Finput-overview-example.ts,src%2Ftheme.scss)